# How to add class to appending td elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a blinking color on a table row with jquery

```
(function blink() {
 $('.colorredd').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500, blink);
 })();
```

here the html part.

```
  <table id="userdata3" border="2">
 <thead>
   <th>Afdeling</th>
  <th>Åben</th>
 </thead>
<tbody  class="colorredd"></tbody>
 </table>
```

here the way how I append the items:

```
$(obj).each(function () {
var tbl3Row = "<tr " + (parseInt(obj.Total) > 3 ? " class='colorred'" : "") + (parseInt(obj.Total) < 4 ? " class='colorred'" : "") + ">" + "<td>" + obj.Title + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj.Total + "</td>" + "</tr>"
 table3Rows += tbl3Row;
});
 }
```

It blinks both rows on table.
What I am trying to do is blink only the second row.
I am guessing that i need to add class to beyond Total td and just remove the class from html tbody.
But I dont know how I can add class to that td specifically.

```
var tbl3Row = "<tr " + (parseInt(obj.Total) > 3 ? " class='colorred'" : "") + (parseInt(obj.Total) < 4 ? " class='colorred'" : "") + ">" + "<td>" + obj.Title + "</td>" + "**<td>**" + obj.Total + "</td>" + "</tr>"
```

and her the my css:

```
.colorred td:nth-child(2){
    background-color:red;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It blinks both rows because you are binding fadeIn/Out to `colorredd` class. which is on every row.

Add another class, maybe `lastRow` to only the last table row. And bind blink to it.

```
(function blink() {
 $('.lastRow').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500, blink);
 })();
```

Comment: yes I am aware of that i need to bind it to last row. The problem is how am I suppose to do that. It's dynamic row not a static one.

Comment: If its one time creating the rows from `obj` array then you can add a condition inside the `each` to find the last index(obj.length-1 === index). If you are dynamically adding more rows, then you have to remove the class which is already there and add it to newly added row.